# How to implement sticky session in spring-integration tcp gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am currently working on a tcp socket server using spring integration.
so far i have below mentioned code.
But there are possibilities of load balance multiple nodes of this socket server. For that I need to have stick sessions of socket connections context which can be shared between nodes. Can anyone suggest possible solution?

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow listnerServerFlow(
            TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory,
            DeviceListenerService deviceListenerService) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Tcp.inboundGateway(serverConnectionFactory))
                .handle(deviceListenerService::processRequest)
                .get();
    }

@Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(2424);
        connectionFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer());
        connectionFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer());
        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        connectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setting

```
connectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
```

there is only one shared connection so it is always sticky (to one server).

You can use a [ThreadAffinityConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-affinity-cf) to bind a connection to each calling thread.

Answer (score 2):

In a common case, you can add a unique identifier in the request and store the session data in a separate Redis.

No matter which node is handling the request, the node can retrieve the session data from the Redis given the identifier in the request.

Hopefully, that can help you work out a solution.

Comment: I am having a requirement exactly similar to the solution you have suggested . Do you have reference towards a sample implementation?

Comment: @ARUNKUMAR I have no example, but it should not be hard. You can add a session id in every request/response header(could be handled in the filters or request/response interceptors), then in the backend retrieve the session data from Redis with given session id in the header.